# How to force ls terminal command to show results in Bytes while I have set the default to ls -h in bash profile?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, terminal

I am following the snippet [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/05/improve-terminal-appearance-mac-os-x/) to improve my terminal command in Mac OSX.

It sets the default value of ls results to human readable by exporting `alias ls='ls -GFh'` to bash profile file. This is very handy, but occasionally I want to see exact size of a file in bytes (in order to compare it with another file).

How can I do that? is there a command I can use ls with to force it show results in bytes?

Is there other command I can use to get file size?

I thought of `du -s` but it would give me just an estimation of used disk space for that file and also minimum size is kilobyte blocks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Is there other command I can use to get file size?

Use one of the following:

```
wc -c file
```

`-c` prints the byte count.

```
\ls -ln file
```

`\` escapes the `ls` alias.

Linux:

```
stat --format="%s" file
```

OS X:

```
stat -f "%z bytes" file
```

See Stack Overflow question [Portable way to get file size (in bytes) in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815329/portable-way-to-get-file-size-in-bytes-in-shell) for other alternatives.

Comment: With OS X El Capitan, `stat --format="%s" file` didn't work for me. Did you mean `stat -f '%z' file`?

Comment: @creidhne Just looked it up. `stat -f "%z bytes" file` is what you need. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

For people reaching this topic and willing to stick to `ls` tool, I would suggest:

`\ls -lb`

`-n` (in `ls -ln`) would be too numerical for my eyes, I'd rather keep user/group readable with `-b`.

Or more conveniently:

`alias lsb='command ls --color -lb'`   # where "`command ls`" is a synonym of "`\ls`"

Answer (score 0):

Running "ls" through the full path will show you the file sizes in bytes:

```
/bin/ls -l
```

Verified on macOS 10.15 with Bash.